# Add BrinIndex to existing PostgreSQL database using Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, indexing

I am running a website using Django, of which the database runs on PostgreSQL. To increase performance I want to add a BrinIndex to a model that is naturally ordered on disk.

I have added the index to my models definition as follows.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import BrinIndex

class Measurement(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            BrinIndex(fields=['time'])
        )

    time = models.DateTimeField(
        'Time of measurement',
        null=True
    )
```

But running

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

Returns an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.1\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_command()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.1\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/Users/*USERNAME*/*PROJECT_NAME*\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\*USERNAME*\*PROJECT_NAME*\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\*USERNAME*\*PROJECT_NAME*\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\*USERNAME*\*PROJECT_NAME*\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\*USERNAME*\*PROJECT_NAME*\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\*USERNAME*\*PROJECT_NAME*\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/Users/*USERNAME*/*PROJECT_NAME*\*APP_NAME*\models.py", line 300, in <module>
    class Measurement(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\*USERNAME*\*PROJECT_NAME*\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 298, in __new__
    new_class._meta.indexes = [copy.deepcopy(idx) for idx in new_class._meta.indexes]
TypeError: 'BrinIndex' object is not iterable
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can this index not be added afterwards?

Comment: Are you importing `django.contrib.postgres.indexes` in your models.py?

Comment: Also, which version of Django are you using? `BrinIndex` is only supported in version *1.11* and above.

Comment: I have imported BrinIndex and I'm running Django 2.0

Comment: Did you check if the field is **NULL** affects the ability to index (see my answer)?

Answer (score 2):

here is the problem of your code
when defining tuples with a single value you have to put "," at the end of the value otherwise python won't recognize it as a tuple for example:

```
a = ('value1') #is a string not a tuple
a = ('value1',) #is a tuple
```

here is what your code should look like:
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import BrinIndex

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            BrinIndex(fields=['time']),  # "," is added here
        )

    time = models.DateTimeField(
        'Time of measurement',
        null=True
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1. You can't *always* have an index on a **NULL** field. I don't know the inner workings of `BrinIndex` but it's something you might like to check.
2. Your model definition should include a `db_index` attribute:

```python
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import BrinIndex

class Measurement(models.Model):

    time = models.DateTimeField(
        'Time of measurement',
        db_index=True,
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            BrinIndex(fields=['time'])
        )
```

Comment: #2 is not quite correct.  
From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques) :  
>Use Meta.indexes or Field.db_index